# MYSQL Get last record where the start time is equal to the previous records end time

Tags: mysql

I have a database as follows.

```
| p_id | p_start_date | p_start_time | p_end_date | p_end_time | p_order |
| 2    |  2017-06-01  |     00:00    | 2017-06-01 |   01:00    |   1     |
| 4    |  2017-06-01  |     01:00    | 2017-06-01 |   02:15    |   2     |
| 1    |  2017-06-02  |     00:00    | 2017-06-02 |   01:30    |   3     |
| 3    |  2017-06-03  |     00:00    | 2017-06-03 |   00:30    |   4     |
```

I would like to move p_id 2 and 4 on 15 minutes.
How would i do this with the following:

```
UPDATE 
  press as p 
SET 
  p.p_start_date = cast(DATE_ADD(CONCAT(p.p_start_date, ' ', p.p_start_time ), INTERVAL 15 MINUTE) as DATE),
  p.p_start_time = cast(DATE_ADD(CONCAT(p.p_start_date, ' ', p.p_start_time), INTERVAL 15 MINUTE) as TIME),
  p.p_end_date = cast(DATE_ADD(CONCAT(p.p_end_date, ' ', p.p_end_time), INTERVAL 15 MINUTE) as DATE),
  p.p_end_time = cast(DATE_ADD(CONCAT(p.p_end_date, ' ', p.p_end_time), INTERVAL 15 MINUTE) as TIME),
  p.p_order = p.p_order + 1
WHERE 
  p.p_order >= 1 AND p.p_order <= 2
```

However I do not know what the last `p_order` is going to be as there could be many jobs following on from each other.

Do you know how I would find this out?

Comment: What about code formatting?

Comment: Is that better? Didn't realise it would be so far of with out the code tags.

Comment: @S.Goodwin what You mean? (:

Comment: num8er - I know 2 needs to be updated as this is what is moving on but how do I find 4 and any others without doing a lot of selects in php as I do not want any to conflict with each other but i also do not want to move 1 on as this would not conflict as it is the next day.

Answer (score 0):

Try selecting the smallest Id which doesn't end when the last one starts, e.g.:

```
SELECT min(t2.id) from MyTable t1 LEFT JOIN MyTable t2 on t1.id - 1 = t2.id and t1.id >  2 WHERE t1.end_date = t2.start_date and t1.end_time = t2.start_time
```

It would make it easier if you could use DateTime instead of 2 seperate fields, though